# execute two query simultaneously insert and update

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute two query simultaneously insert  and update query wheres my when I use update query my insert query not working but update query working Please help to solve this problem.

```
  <?php



    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my");
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `kyc`( `date`,`agentid`,`formno`, `bank`, `ptype`,
   `cardno`,      `cname`, `fname`, `mname`, `dob`, `phone`, `votarid`,`sex`, 
   `email`, `district`, `thana`)
   VALUES('$date','$agentid',$formno,'$bank','$ptype','$cardno','$cname','$fname',
    '$mname','$dob',$phone,$votarid,'$sex','$email','$district','$thana')";
    $sql="UPDATE card SET status='1'WHERE $cardno=`cardno`";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   echo "One raw Successfully inserted";




    mysqli_close($con);
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: How about creating a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing trigger. So whenever insert happening trigger will execute.

These links will help you to learn triggers
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/

If you really want execute update as query you can try your query by adding `;` at the end of insert query.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `kyc`( `date`,`agentid`,`formno`, `bank`, `ptype`,
   `cardno`,      `cname`, `fname`, `mname`, `dob`, `phone`, `votarid`,`sex`, 
   `email`, `district`, `thana`)
   VALUES('$date','$agentid',$formno,'$bank','$ptype','$cardno','$cname','$fname',
    '$mname','$dob',$phone,$votarid,'$sex','$email','$district','$thana');";
                                                                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `kyc`( `date`,`agentid`,`formno`, `bank`, `ptype`,
   `cardno`,      `cname`, `fname`, `mname`, `dob`, `phone`, `votarid`,`sex`, 
   `email`, `district`, `thana`)
   VALUES('$date','$agentid',$formno,'$bank','$ptype','$cardno','$cname','$fname',
    '$mname','$dob',$phone,$votarid,'$sex','$email','$district','$thana')";

$sql_update="UPDATE card SET status='1'WHERE $cardno=`cardno`";

$sql=$sql_insert.";".$sql_update;

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

Using multi_query, you can run multiple queries in just one sentence.

Look into: http://docs.php.net/mysqli.multi-query
for more information!

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp2\htdocs\finalkyc\kycapps.php on line 206

Fatal error: Call to a member function multi_query() on a non-object in C:\xampp2\htdocs\finalkyc\kycapps.php on line 206

Comment: Try: http://docs.php.net/mysqli.multi-query section Procedural style below examples.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run 2 SQL statements consecutively:

The first statement is an INSERT, the second an UPDATE.

at the moment you're only executing the UPDATE, because you're resetting $sql to the UPDATE statement without running the INSERT query first

You should execute them one after the other:

> $sql = "INSERT INTO `kyc`( `date`,`agentid`,`formno`, `bank`, `ptype`,
>   `cardno`,      `cname`, `fname`, `mname`, `dob`, `phone`,
>   `votarid`,`sex`,     `email`, `district`, `thana`)
>   VALUES('$date','$agentid',$formno,'$bank','$ptype','$cardno','$cname','$fname',
>        '$mname','$dob',$phone,$votarid,'$sex','$email','$district','$thana')";
>
> $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);   //check for errors
>
> $sql="UPDATE card SET status='1' WHERE $cardno=`cardno`";
>
> $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

or separate them with a semi-colon ';'

> $sql = "INSERT INTO `kyc`( `date`,`agentid`,`formno`, `bank`, `ptype`,
>   `cardno`,      `cname`, `fname`, `mname`, `dob`, `phone`,
>   `votarid`,`sex`,     `email`, `district`, `thana`)
>   VALUES('$date','$agentid',$formno,'$bank','$ptype','$cardno','$cname','$fname',
>        '$mname','$dob',$phone,$votarid,'$sex','$email','$district','$thana')";
>
> $sql .="; UPDATE card SET status='1' WHERE $cardno=`cardno`";
>
> $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

Answer (score 0):

you can write them and separate by ;

```
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my");
   // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `kyc`( `date`,`agentid`,`formno`, `bank`, `ptype`,
 `cardno`,      `cname`, `fname`, `mname`, `dob`, `phone`, `votarid`,`sex`, 
 `email`, `district`, `thana`)
 VALUES('$date','$agentid',$formno,'$bank','$ptype','$cardno','$cname','$fname',
'$mname','$dob',$phone,$votarid,'$sex','$email','$district','$thana')";

$sql_update="UPDATE card SET status='1'WHERE $cardno=`cardno`";
```

$sql=$sql_insert.";".$sql_update;

```
  $result_insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


 echo "One raw Successfully inserted";




  mysqli_close($con);
```

}